# Не получается добавить спрайты

Tags: python, разработка-игр, pygame

я застрял на моменте когда захотел добавить в игру спрайт при передвижении в лево или в право. В этом тестовом коде у меня получилось сделать желаемое Вот код:

```
from idlelib import window
import random
import pygame

from turtle import width as t_width


pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 500))


pygame.display.set_caption("Cubes")

walkRight = [pygame.image.load('right_1.png'), pygame.image.load('right_2.png'), pygame.image.load('right_3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('right_4.png'), pygame.image.load('right_5.png'), pygame.image.load('right_6.png')]

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('left_1.png'), pygame.image.load('left_2.png'), pygame.image.load('left_3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('left_4.png'), pygame.image.load('left_5.png'), pygame.image.load('left_6.png')]

JumpRight = [pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_1.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_2.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_4.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_5.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_6.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_7.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_8.png'),
             pygame.image.load('Jump_Right_9.png')]

JumpLeft = [pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_1.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_2.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_4.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_5.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_6.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_7.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_8.png'),
            pygame.image.load('Jump_Left_9.png')]


bg = pygame.image.load('bg2.png')
playerStand = pygame.image.load('ninja.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = 50
y = 249
width = 48
height = 66
speed = 8


isJump = False
JumpCount = 10

left = False
right = False
animCount = 0



def drawWindow():
    global animCount
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    if animCount + 1 >= 30:
        animCount = 0

    if left:
        win.blit(walkLeft[animCount // 5], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    elif right:
        win.blit(walkRight[animCount // 5], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    else:
        win.blit(playerStand, (x, y))


    pygame.display.update()



        





run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(40)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 249 and x > 380 and x < 410:
        y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 450 - width - 5 and x > 380 and x < 410  :
        y += speed

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 10:
        x -= speed
        left = True
        right = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 1200 - width - 10:
        x += speed
        left = False
        right = True
    else:
        left = False
        right = False
        animCount = 0





    if not(isJump):

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True

    else:
        if JumpCount >= -10:
            if JumpCount < 0:
                y += (JumpCount ** 2) / 2
            else:
                y -= (JumpCount ** 2) / 2
            JumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            JumpCount = 10




    if keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
            run = False



    drawWindow()
```

Решил сделать тоже самое в другом коде но не получилось, я не знаю в чём моя ощибка Помогите пожалуйста добавить спрайты при передвижении в право и в лево в этом коде: Код:

```
import pygame
import random
# Переменные для установки ширины и высоты окна
SCREEN_WIDTH = 1350
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 950
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('right_1.png'), pygame.image.load('right_2.png'), pygame.image.load('right_3.png'),
             pygame.image.load('right_4.png'), pygame.image.load('right_5.png'), pygame.image.load('right_6.png')]

walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('left_1.png'), pygame.image.load('left_2.png'), pygame.image.load('left_3.png'),
            pygame.image.load('left_4.png'), pygame.image.load('left_5.png'), pygame.image.load('left_6.png')]

# Подключение фото для заднего фона
# Здесь лишь создание переменной, вывод заднего фона ниже в коде
bg = pygame.image.load('bg3.jpg')
animCount = 0
def drawWindow():
    global animCount
    win.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    if animCount + 1 >= 30:
        animCount = 0

    if go_left(self):
        win.blit(walkLeft[animCount // 5], (x, y))
        animCount += 1
    elif go_right(self):
        win.blit(walkRight[animCount // 5], (x, y))
        animCount += 1



    pygame.display.update()
# Класс, описывающий поведение главного игрока
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    # Изначально игрок смотрит вправо, поэтому эта переменная True
    right = True

    # Методы
    def __init__(self):
        # Стандартный конструктор класса
        # Нужно ещё вызывать конструктор родительского класса
        super().__init__()

        # Создаем изображение для игрока
        # Изображение находится в этой же папке проекта
        self.image = pygame.image.load('ninja.png')

        # Установите ссылку на изображение прямоугольника
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        # Задаем вектор скорости игрока
        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0

    def update(self):
        # В этой функции мы передвигаем игрока
        # Сперва устанавливаем для него гравитацию
        self.calc_grav()

        # Передвигаем его на право/лево
        # change_x будет меняться позже при нажатии на стрелочки клавиатуры
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        # Следим ударяем ли мы какой-то другой объект, платформы, например
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        # Перебираем все возможные объекты, с которыми могли бы столкнуться
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # Если мы идем направо,
            # устанавливает нашу правую сторону на левой стороне предмета, которого мы ударили
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:
                # В противном случае, если мы движемся влево, то делаем наоборот
                self.rect.left = block.rect.right

        # Передвигаемся вверх/вниз
        self.rect.y += self.change_y

        # То же самое, вот только уже для вверх/вниз
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # Устанавливаем нашу позицию на основе верхней / нижней части объекта, на который мы попали
            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self.change_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom

            # Останавливаем вертикальное движение
            self.change_y = 0

    def calc_grav(self):
        # Здесь мы вычисляем как быстро объект будет
        # падать на землю под действием гравитации
        if self.change_y == 0:
            self.change_y = 1
        else:
            self.change_y += .95

        # Если уже на земле, то ставим позицию Y как 0
        if self.rect.y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.change_y >= 0:
            self.change_y = 0
            self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height

    def jump(self):
        # Обработка прыжка
        # Нам нужно проверять здесь, контактируем ли мы с чем-либо
        # или другими словами, не находимся ли мы в полете.
        # Для этого опускаемся на 10 единиц, проверем соприкосновение и далее поднимаемся обратно
        self.rect.y += 10
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 10

        # Если все в порядке, прыгаем вверх
        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.change_y = -16

    # Передвижение игрока
    def go_left(self):
        global animCount
        # Сами функции будут вызваны позже из основного цикла
        self.change_x = -9 # Двигаем игрока по Х
        if(self.right): # Проверяем куда он смотрит и если что, то переворачиваем его
            self.flip()
            self.right = False
        else:
            animCount = 0

    def go_right(self):
        global animCount
        # то же самое, но вправо
        self.change_x = 9
        if (not self.right):
            self.flip()
            self.right = True
        else:
            animCount = 0

    def stop(self):
        # вызываем этот метод, когда не нажимаем на клавиши
        self.change_x = 0

    def flip(self):
        # переворот игрока (зеркальное отражение)
        self.image = pygame.transform.flip(self.image, True, False)


# Класс для описания платформы
class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, width, height):
        # Конструктор платформ
        super().__init__()
        # Также указываем фото платформы
        self.image = pygame.image.load('platform3.png')

        # Установите ссылку на изображение прямоугольника
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


# Класс для расстановки платформ на сцене
class Level(object):
    def __init__(self, player):
        # Создаем группу спрайтов (поместим платформы различные сюда)
        self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        # Ссылка на основного игрока
        self.player = player

    # Чтобы все рисовалось, то нужно обновлять экран
    # При вызове этого метода обновление будет происходить
    def update(self):
        self.platform_list.update()

    # Метод для рисования объектов на сцене
    def draw(self, screen):
        # Рисуем задний фон
        screen.blit(bg, (0, 0))

        # Рисуем все платформы из группы спрайтов
        self.platform_list.draw(screen)


# Класс, что описывает где будут находится все платформы
# на определенном уровне игры
class Level_01(Level):
    def __init__(self, player):
        # Вызываем родительский конструктор
        Level.__init__(self, player)

        # Массив с данными про платформы. Данные в таком формате:
        # ширина, высота, x и y позиция
        level = [
            [70, 10, 0, 820],
            [70, 10, 335, 720],
            [70, 10, 50, 600],
            [70, 10, 50, 465],
            [70, 10, 490, 465],

        ]

        # Перебираем массив и добавляем каждую платформу в группу спрайтов - platform_list
        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)


# Основная функция прогарммы
def main():
    # Инициализация
    pygame.init()

    # Установка высоты и ширины
    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

    # Название игры
    pygame.display.set_caption("Платформер")

    # Создаем игрока
    player = Player()

    # Создаем все уровни
    level_list = []
    level_list.append(Level_01(player))

    # Устанавливаем текущий уровень
    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]

    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level

    player.rect.x = 0
    player.rect.y = 120
    active_sprite_list.add(player)

    # Цикл будет до тех пор, пока пользователь не нажмет кнопку закрытия
    done = False

    # Используется для управления скоростью обновления экрана
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    # Основной цикл программы
    while not done:
        # Отслеживание действий
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT: # Если закрыл программу, то останавливаем цикл
                done = True

            # Если нажали на стрелки клавиатуры, то двигаем объект
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.go_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.go_right()
                if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    player.jump()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.change_x < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.change_x > 0:
                    player.stop()

        # Обновляем игрока
        active_sprite_list.update()

        # Обновляем объекты на сцене
        current_level.update()

        # Если игрок приблизится к правой стороне, то дальше его не двигаем
        if player.rect.right > SCREEN_WIDTH:
            player.rect.right = SCREEN_WIDTH

        # Если игрок приблизится к левой стороне, то дальше его не двигаем
        if player.rect.left < 0:
            player.rect.left = 0

        # Рисуем объекты на окне
        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)



        # Устанавливаем количество фреймов
        clock.tick(30)
    # Обновляем экран после рисования объектов
        pygame.display.flip()

    # Корректное закртытие программы
pygame.quit()
main()
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить анимацию при передвижении в сторону](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1143542/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%83)

Comment: сделал это из за того что в вопросе  Как добавить анимацию при передвижении в сторону я не совсем верно написал заголовок

Comment: Вы можете редактировать заголовок вопроса с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1143542/edit) под вопросом

Comment: Спасибо , я недавно на этом сайте  поэтому не знал об этом